# Typed Arrays and normal Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Since typed arrays are just normal Arrays with typed values, they should also be considered "Arrays". But when I test if typed arrays are arrays, it returns `false`. For example:

```
var arr = new Int32Array(3);
Array.isArray(arr);            //false
```

Does `Array.isArray` only check if `arr` is exactly a type `Array` object? How can I test if `arr` is an array, regardless of typed or not typed?

Comment: *"Since typed arrays are just normal Arrays with typed values"* What do you consider as "normal array"? Typed arrays don't inherit from `Array.prototype`. It's very likely that the browser implements them completely differently than "normal" arrays. It looks like this is fixed [in ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.isarray) (although I don't know what "exotic array" means in this case, *edit:* Now I do: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array-exotic-objects).

Comment: Typed arrays are not a part of ECMA-262, while `Array.prototype.isArray` is. It's not surprising that the latter does not exhibit the behavior you want regarding the former.

Comment: @FelixKling - Okay if I assume they are completely different than untyped arrays, how can I know if they are an Array? There seems to be no `.isArray` or similar methods under `Int32Array`.

Comment: I guess you have to fall back to one of the many custom  implementations that detect array-like objects, or actually use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I came up with:

```
isArray = /Array/.test(arr.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Typed Arrays are very different beasts than arrays.  Arrays are generic collections, with loads of helper-methods for operating on those collections.

Typed Arrays were put in primarily to help with the browser version of OpenGL (though they obviously have other uses).

Try calling `typedInt8Array.forEach()`...
They're not the same thing.

So if you want a function which checks whether a variable/property is an array, or a typed array, then you will have to manually check the `instanceof` for each of the `Int8Array|Int16Array|etc...`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to this trick:

```
obj.length === +obj.length; // true if it's an array
```

Since JavaScript Arrays have the special length property this is a pretty safe way to tell unless you have objects that you've defined a length property on manually.

Comment: `var obj = "ab"; obj.length === +obj.length;  //true` (although technically a String is an Array)

Comment: `var obj = function(){}; obj.length === +obj.length;  //true`

Answer (score 0):

Since Typed Arrays still have a length property, the old trick

```
obj.length === +obj.length
```

still works.

That means that length is a numeric property ( +v transforms a var to number, so if it's still === after the transform, then it was a number to begin with).

Comment: Looks like you haven't seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22135017/218196) which was posted 15min before you posted yours.

Comment: spot question, do research, find answer, submit answer, page refreshes, realize only now others have posted answers too in the meantime, go oh well, get smart comment... oh well...

Comment: Yep, SO is a tough place.